# Imacros doesn't see the js file

Tags: imacros

I've written the js file using Imacros commands. But Imacros didn't detect the js file.
[image]
[image]
 I'm using MacOs and Chrome browser. How can I run my "123.js" file?

Comment: Chrome DOESN'T see .js files. FireFox DOES.

Comment: @macroscripts omfg! Thanks!